# How to add a conditional scroll based on window size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I'm working on a react app and I basically want to include a scroll bar for smaller window sizes such as a mobile device.  So a scroll bar would if and only if the window size is smaller than the menu itself.

What I have so far as a hacky fix.

```js
    const styles = {

        dropdownContentClass: {
            maxHeight: "15 em",
            overflowY: "auto",
        }
    }
```

Here I force a max height on the menu so its always scrollable but I would like to have a scroll available if a user is on mobile or the window size is relatively small.

EDIT:

```
var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)")
    if (mq.matches){
        var mh = "15em"
        var oy = "scroll"
    }
    return {maxHeight: mh, overflowY: oy}
```

So I got it to work this this sort of hacky fix.  Still kind of new to Javascript but its pretty hard to confirm your code when theres millions of ways to do something.

Comment: you'll want to look into `@media` with a `max-height` value and set the overflow-y in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap everything into a media query which will apply from smaller devices such as mobiles, up to a maximum width you want the scrollbar to stop being displayed.

Example :

```
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
      dropdownContentClass: {
            maxHeight: "15 em",
            overflowY: "scroll",
        }
}
```

This way, your little workaround will only apply for devices with a maximum of 768px, on tablets or desktops will stop

Answer (score 2):

The browser will have scrollbars by default if the content exceeds the height of the window, so this should already work. If you have a container that has a fixed height that's wrapping your page, like one that's absolutely positioned, you'll need to add `overflow-y: auto` to it as well.